# How to apply join on tables while using having function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

There are two tables - **trans** and **customer**.

**trans**

| customerid | pdate | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11-01-2021 | 200 |
| 2 | 13-02-2021 | 400 |
| 1 | 18-01-2021 | 400 |
| 3 | 31-01-2021 | 600 |
| 4 | 23-03-2021 | 700 |

**customer**

| customerid | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | raj | sharma |
| 2 | rahul | dev |
| 3 | riya | sen |
| 4 | rose | menon |

The question is -

**Find the firstname, lastname and sum of the purchase of the customers where sum of the purchase is greater than 500 in the month of January (Without using any CTE).**

My take on this was -

```
SELECT
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname,
    SUM( t.purchase )
FROM
    customer c
    INNER JOIN trans t ON c.id = t.id
GROUP BY
    c.firstname,
    c.lastname
HAVING
    SUM( t.purchase ) > 500;
```

But this ignores the customers with id 1. The customerid 1 has made a purchase twice and the sum of his purchase is greater than 500.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is this a typo? `INNER JOIN trans t ON c.id = t.id`, as your schema shows `customerid` as the key. Also, your query doesn't filter to January purchases.

Comment: Your query should work (leaving apart the point noted by Ryan Wilson). Note that `GROUP BY c.id` would be safer than by first name / last name. Two different customers *may* have the same name, I imagine.

Comment: What do you mean it 'ignores' the customer? Can you show your resultset?

Comment: Everyone, please accept my apology, and Ryan Wilson was correct, it was a typo.